# Save UITextField inside of a UITableViewCell to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uitextfield

Alright, I know this question has been asked before, but mine has a different issue than the others.

I have a text field inside of a custom tableview cell that I need to save to an array after the number pad is dismissed. Since the number pad has no done button, I had to implement a touch event to dismiss the number pad. That means my -textFieldDidEndEditing is not firing. Here is the relevant code:

in my viewController.h

```
itemData *tempItem; //A custom object    
UITableView *itemsListTable;
NSMutableArray *listData;
```

in my viewController.m

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

       static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";


        UITableViewCell *cell = [itemsListTable
                                 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];


        NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
        tempItem = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [tempItem getItemName];


        UITextField *quantityTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(275, 8, 35, 27)];
        quantityTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        quantityTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        quantityTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        quantityTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tempItem.getItemQuantity];
        quantityTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;


        [cell addSubview:quantityTextField];
        } 


        return cell;

    }

-(void)touchesEnded: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {
[[self itemsListTable] endEditing:YES];
    }
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)textField.superview;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.itemsListTable indexPathForCell:cell];

    tempItem = [listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Did End Editing");
    [tempItem setItemQuantity:[textField.text intValue]]; //save textfield to object as intValue

    [listData replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:tempItem]; //save object to array
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [listData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [itemsListTable reloadData];
    }    
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    numberOfItems.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",listData.count];

    return [self.listData count];
}
```

Comment: In additional, for good naming convention, all classes' name should be started with capital letter, e.g. `ItemData` instead of `itemData`.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I only posted code pertaining to the UITableView or the UITextField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your touch event dismisses the keyboard, also call [self textFieldDidEndEditing:], or if you need to know which text field had focus last, keep a reference by defining a UITextField object that you set to the current text field that has first responder in the textFieldDidBeginEditing delegate function. Like this:

```
//In .h
UITextField * txtReference;

//In .m
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    txtReference = textField;
}

//In the function that dismisses the keyboard put:
[self textFieldDidEndEditing:txtReference];
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfect for what I asked! unfortunately I realized I needed a different approach because I have a text field in every cell ;)

Comment: If you have UITextfield in every cell have you thought about making custom cells if your not already.